# What is the difference between the identity functor and the identity morphism?

Tags: category-theory, functors, morphism

The only difference that I can think of is that - because the identity functor is also an endofunctor - its only extra ability is being able to map morphisms to themselves and not just category objects. ("The identity functor maps an object to itself and a morphism to itself.", from `en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor` and morphisms are confined to a category, if I understood it correctly.)

There have been sources where it seems that the two terms have been used interchangeably (e.g., [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Identity_Functor_is_Functor) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302334/understanding-identity-functor)) because the definition provided for the identity functor is the same with definition of the identity morphism at `en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism#Definition`:

> For every object X, there exists a morphism $id_X : X → X$ called the
>   identity morphism on X, such that for every morphism $f : A → B$ we have
>   $id_B ∘ f = f = f ∘ id_A$.

I assume that usually identity functor is used because it is a broader term.

Comment: It's the same as the difference between the identity element of a group and the identity homomorphism on a group.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $X$ is an object in a category $\mathcal C$, the identity morphism $id_X:X\to X$ is a morphism **in the category $\mathcal C$**.

On the other hand, the identity functor is **not** a morphism *in* $\mathcal C$; it is a functor $\mathcal C\to\mathcal C$. A functor takes has two inputs, (i) objects, and (ii) morphisms. So the identity functor $Id_{\mathcal C}$ has, for every object $X$ in $\mathcal C$ and morphism $f:X\to Y$, the values $Id_{\mathcal C}(X)=X$ and $Id_{\mathcal C}(f)=f$.

I think it will be easier to see what's going on if you look at a specific category. So let's say $\mathcal C$ is the category of **Sets**. Then an object in $\mathcal C$ is just a set $X$, and a morphism $f:X\to Y$ is just a set function.

In this case, the identity morphism of a fixed set $X$ is just the identity map on $X$ that you're surely familiar with. It just has the value $id_X(x)=x$ for all $x\in X$.

On the other hand, a **functor** $F:\mathcal C\to\mathcal C$ assigns to *every* set $X$ a new set $F(X)$ and to every morphism $f:X\to Y$ a new morphism $F(f):F(X)\to F(Y)$. In the case of the identity functor, it just takes $X\mapsto X$ and $f\mapsto f$.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer and also for explaining the distinction between functors and morphism - its clear that I had the wrong idea.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\mathcal C$ be a category.

**Definition 1.** (Identity morphism)

> For every object $X$ in $\mathcal C$ there is identity morphism
>   $1_X\colon X\to X$ by definition of category. It satisfies:
>
> $(i)\ $ $1_X\circ f = f$, for all objects $Y$ and morphisms $f\colon
>  Y\to X$,
>
> $(ii) $ $f\circ 1_X = f$, for all objects $Y$ and morphisms $f\colon
>  X\to Y$.

**Definition 2.** (Identity functor)

> There is a functor $I_\mathcal C\colon\mathcal C\to\mathcal C$
>   with property:
>
> $(i)\ $  $I_\mathcal CX = X$, for every object $X$,
>
> $(ii)$ $I_\mathcal Cf = f$, for every pair of objects $X,Y$ and
>   morphism $f\colon X\to Y$.

Given category of small categories $\mathrm{Cat}$, where objects are small categories and morphisms are functors, identity morphism on category $\mathcal C$ in $\mathrm{Cat}$ is given by identity functor $I_\mathcal C$. Thus, identity functors can be seen as a special case of identity morphisms in case of category $\mathrm {Cat}$.

Comment: I chose @Sheaf's answer because it was exactly what I needed. I'll use your as answer as reference though (and upvote it as soon as I have the reps) because I've been googling a while now but this is the first time I saw the clear definitions of both (not to mention side-by-side). I especially liked the special case example as I am new to category theory and I got to appreciate it even more.

Comment: @toraritte, I'd recommend that you go through [Basic Category Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09375) by Tom Leinster.

Answer (score 1):

A morphism is something which lives in $\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)$ for some pair of objects $X,Y \in \mathfrak{C}$, for some category $\mathfrak{C}$. A functor is an object defined on the objects and morphisms of a category, which takes objects of some category $\mathfrak{C}$ and returns objects of some other category $\mathfrak{D}$.

So the identity morphism is a morphism from some object to itself, and the identity functor is a functor which returns the object and morphism that it eats.

In short, the difference is one of scope. A functor is defined on the entire category, and a morphism is defined only on object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the simple language and the upvote is coming too. Your last paragraph is golden: "scope" is exactly the term that will help me remember the distinction and the 2nd sentence is the perfect summary on the functor vs morphism topic.